# 400 Bad Request error suddenly on Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a working project with angular and nodejs as backend. everything was working fine but suddenly I get a 400 Bad Request response and CORS error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4900/version' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   the point here is that angular calls this api many times from different locations;

for ex. http://localhost:4200/login calls http://localhost:4900/version and retrieve the version while  http://localhost:4200/settings page calls the same api but get the cors header exception. 
nothing changed in nodejs server;

```
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    app = express();
const verifyToken = require('./api/lib/verifyToken');

app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
```

the application is working on production server with no error but not working in my local environment. 
the api call made and working 
[image: working request]

the none working request 
[image: none working request]

[image: console image]

Comment: Do you get the exception if you change app.options('*' ... by app.options('localhost:4200', ... ?

Comment: @JulienGabriel yes I do get the exception. yesterday it was working fine!

Comment: Can you show us how the API calls are made ?

Comment: i did add soem images

Comment: The https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8jHt.png screenshot shows that your code is getting a 400 Bad Request response. That’s the problem you need to fix. You don’t have a CORS problem. The only reason the browser is logging a CORS message is because the server doesn’t add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to 4xx errors. But even if that 400 error did have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, it’d still be a 400 error. Check the server logs on the server side and see what messages the server is logging there before it sends back that 400 response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker as i said in the post why the localhost:4200/login calls the version api and works while localhost:422/setting is not working

Comment: did you try to add manual cors allow code in expressJS? try to add this code and debug it.   
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
 });

Comment: @FarukT I did add manually but nothing changed.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I added console image that shows the CORS error

Comment: I found out that it might be a user-specific situation!